# What is the ultimate way to configure logging in Django?

Tags: python, django, logging

There are many examples online but what is the best way to configure the LOGGING Dictionary in settings.py to capture everything that is going on with the solution and it's associated apps - from small errors to sql/model calls.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout  [the Django logging doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging) and these answers may be useful [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438642/django-setup-default-logging)

and customize according to your application

hope this helps you