# Configure Apache/Django on elastic beanstalk to address INVALID_HOST errors

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Background:**

Current setup is

- Have a website hosted in AWS S3 (e.g. app.com)
- Have api server hosted in elastic beanstalk (e.g. api.com)
- Website makes api requests to api server

ALLOWED_HOST has been set in Django so that it includes

- The elastic beanstalk address
- The url for the api

**Issues:**

- The web app is working fine. However, I am seeing numerous requests to the api from random urls (bots, exploits, etc). This is firing off hundreds of `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` errors. I could obviously turn off the error notification, but that does not feel right.
- The log suggests adding bunch of ip addresses to the ALLOWED_HOST, most of which is the ip address of my load balancer. However, as my regular api requests are going through without problem, I doubt adding the IP address of load balancer to ALLOWED_HOST is the solution either.
- So that would leave changing the load balancer itself so that it does not direct requests to Django if it is invalid. I have found a few answer with regards to this such as

  - [How to disable Django's invalid HTTP_HOST error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220519/how-to-disable-djangos-invalid-http-host-error)
  - [Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header on Apache - fix using Require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513109/django-invalid-http-host-header-on-apache-fix-using-require)

Two questions:

- Is the above modification the correct way to handle this problem?
- Is there a way to apply this programmatically to Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Will appreciate any help

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These are probably the elastic beanstalk healthcheck calls.  These come from an IP address.

Try adding to `settings.py`

```
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname  # For AWS Healthchecker
HOST_NAME = gethostname()
HOST_IP = gethostbyname(HOST_NAME)
ALLOWED_HOSTS [ 
    ...
    HOME_NAME, HOME_IP,
    ...
]
```