# Django - Helicon Zoo - Application backend read Error

Tags: python, django, iis, amazon-ec2, heliconzoo

## Django on a clean Server 2012R2 instance (Amazon EC2)

- I've tried setting up a django site using instructions found here: [Helicon Zoo Django setup](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/)
- I'm using Helizon Zoo module version 3.1.98.538 (this is from the beta feed as suggested here: [Helicon zoo forum](http://www.helicontech.com/community/Zoo_Python_crashes-6-2968.html?p=6704&hilit=backend%20read%20Error#p6704))
- Browsing to **localhost/ZooPythonProject**, I get the base python project page, this works before I install django.
- Once django is installed and I change the options in web.config as suggested, once I refresh the page I get a internal server 500 error:

-

```
Error:
Helicon Zoo module has caught up an error. Please see the details below.

Worker Status:
The process was created

Windows error:  
The pipe has been ended. (ERROR CODE: 109)

Internal module error:   
message: Application backend read Error. type: ZooException file: App\Jobs\JobBase.cpp line: 531 version: 3.1.98.538 

STDERR:  
Empty stderr

Environment variables:  
ALLUSERSPROFILE C:\ProgramData 
APPDATA C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming 
APPL_ID ZooPythonProject 
APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject 
APPL_PHYSICAL_SHORT_PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZOOPYT~1 
APPL_VIRTUAL_PATH /ZooPythonProject 
APP_POOL_CONFIG C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\ZooPythonProject\ZooPythonProject.config 
APP_POOL_ID ZooPythonProject 
COMMONPROGRAMFILES C:\Program Files\Common Files 
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files 
COMMONPROGRAMW6432 C:\Program Files\Common Files 
COMPUTERNAME WIN-IAK09MB251B 
COMSPEC C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe 
CONSOLE_URL console 
DEPLOY_FILE deploy.py 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project.settings 
ERROR_LOG_DIR log 
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK NO 
HOST 127.0.0.1 
IIS_BINDNGS http=*:80: 
INSTANCE_ID 1 
LOCALAPPDATA C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local 
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS 1 
OS Windows_NT 
PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\ 
PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC 
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE AMD64 
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel 
PROCESSOR_LEVEL 6 
PROCESSOR_REVISION 3e04 
PROGRAMDATA C:\ProgramData 
PROGRAMFILES C:\Program Files 
PROGRAMFILES(X86) C:\Program Files (x86) 
PROGRAMW6432 C:\Program Files 
PSMODULEPATH C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\ 
PUBLIC C:\Users\Public 
PYTHONPATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\project 
SITE_NAME DEFAULT WEB SITE 
SITE_PHYSICAL_PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot 
SYSTEMDRIVE C: 
SYSTEMROOT C:\Windows 
TEMP C:\Windows\TEMP 
TMP C:\Windows\TEMP 
USERDOMAIN WORKGROUP 
USERNAME WIN-IAK09MB251B$ 
USERPROFILE C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile 
VIRTUAL_ENV C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv 
WINDIR C:\Windows 

Helicon Zoo engine settings  

appName python.project 
appFullPath C:\python27\python.exe 
appDirectory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject 
appArguments C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py 
deployArguments  
transportName NamedPipe 
protocol fastcgi 
scriptProcessor python.2.7.wsgi 
errorLogDir C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\log 
postBufferDir  
watchFileChangesMask  
host 127.0.0.1 
port %PORT% 
proxyPass  
minInstances 1 
maxInstances 1 
minRequestsPerWorker 3 
maxRequestsPerWorker 15 
portLower 49152 
portUpper 65535 
workerRequestTimeout 30 
timeLimit 0 
postBuffer 1024 
memoryLimit 0 
gracefulShutdownTimeout 30 

Web.config variables  

APPL_ID ZooPythonProject 
APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject 
APPL_PHYSICAL_SHORT_PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZOOPYT~1 
APPL_VIRTUAL_PATH /ZooPythonProject 
CONSOLE_URL console 
DEPLOY_FILE deploy.py 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project.settings 
ERROR_LOG_DIR log 
HOST 127.0.0.1 
IIS_BINDNGS http=*:80: 
INSTANCE_ID 1 
PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\ 
PYTHONPATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\project 
SITE_NAME DEFAULT WEB SITE 
SITE_PHYSICAL_PATH C:\inetpub\wwwroot 
VIRTUAL_ENV C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv
```

Here is the worker error log:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "django.request"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 1069, in <module>
    run_django_app(options.django_settings_module, options.django_root)
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 999, in run_django_app
    FCGIServer(WSGIHandler(), app_root=django_root).run()
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 776, in run
    conn.run()
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 569, in run
    self.process_input()
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 600, in process_input
    self._do_stdin(rec)
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 724, in _do_stdin
    self._start_request(req)
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 697, in _start_request
    req.run()
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 515, in run
    protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
  File "C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py", line 862, in handler
    result = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 199, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 236, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 91, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 350, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 148, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 142, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 844, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 80, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 90, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 624, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaultfilters.py", line 769, in date
    return format(value, arg)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateformat.py", line 343, in format
    return df.format(format_string)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateformat.py", line 35, in format
    pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateformat.py", line 268, in r
    return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateformat.py", line 35, in format
    pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 85, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 144, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 83, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 325, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 306, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 189, in _fetch
    "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

ZooError-0-

```
[08.11.2014 22:08:55.451521] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x000008d8] [sev 2] # 29876311008 Application has been started
[08.11.2014 22:08:55.545260] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x000008d8] [sev 2] # 29876234512 Application has been terminated
ate log file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ZooPythonProject\log\python.project [2014_11_08 22_08_55] worker-1.log
[08.11.2014 22:08:56.154595] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - OnProcessExit()
[08.11.2014 22:08:56.154595] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker shutdown. #2 - [pid:3276] "C:\python27\python.exe" C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py
[08.11.2014 22:09:25.467110] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker closed. #2
[08.11.2014 22:10:02.092102] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - OnProcessExit()
[08.11.2014 22:10:02.092102] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker shutdown. #3 - [pid:2380] "C:\python27\python.exe" C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py
[08.11.2014 22:10:25.467595] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker closed. #3
[08.11.2014 22:13:34.654735] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - OnProcessExit()
[08.11.2014 22:13:34.654735] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker shutdown. #4 - [pid:3852] "C:\python27\python.exe" C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py
[08.11.2014 22:13:56.248576] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker closed. #4
[08.11.2014 22:14:13.139178] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - OnProcessExit()
[08.11.2014 22:14:13.139178] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker shutdown. #5 - [pid:2228] "C:\python27\python.exe" C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py
[08.11.2014 22:14:26.342332] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker closed. #5
[08.11.2014 22:16:54.342382] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - OnProcessExit()
[08.11.2014 22:16:54.342382] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker shutdown. #6 - [pid:2496] "C:\python27\python.exe" C:\Zoo\Workers\python\zoofcgi.py
[08.11.2014 22:16:56.357999] [v 3.1.98.538] [tid 0x00000a9c] [sev 2] WorkersManager - Worker closed. #6
```

Django project settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5jd%y7umf(o%0xa02nd@=(wl(z$$j#nyje^u=*19r*6kg$wfto'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/mylog.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },  
        'request_handler': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/django_request.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['request_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error, i also have been searching in a lot of sites and had no luck, the error is raisen here: `try:
            app_configs = reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs()))
        except AppRegistryNotReady:`. The Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#troubleshooting suggest to run `django.setup()` but I am stucked here... any other idea?

Comment: create a new instance of the python template and install django 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error and posting to the [Helicon Forum](http://www.helicontech.com/community/Django_-_Application_backend_read_Error-6-3290.html?p=7877#p7877)

I've found it just to be an error with the newest version of Django 1.7

After the helicon setup creates the virtual environment (aka python template), install django 1.6 instead

```
pip install django==1.6
```

Server configuration automation can be a pain and I'm sure they're resolving this issue, hopefully the slightly older version is not an issue for you.

If this is a production server you may still want to follow through because of possible security implications, maybe check the django 1.7 change log

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the logger in your Django settings, something like this:

```
    LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            },
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll set up django logging, Your example looks like it's for emailing though; I haven't had a chance to even set up an email within django, fresh install.... I used this instead, [setup django logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438642/django-setup-default-logging)